# Data type not changing in mongo DB after I made changes to mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I recently made changes to my mongoose schema from `String` to `Number`. When I read data from db, it show as Number but when I try making filters based on the changed property, I don't get any document that was saved before the schema changes were made. When I check using Robo 3T, I see the data types are still showing `string`.  I wish to change all to Number. The data type doesn't seem to change even after I make updates to the document.

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema(

 {
    status: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
}...)
```

Here is how it looks like in the DB

[image]

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to`update` all the documents to change the data type.

Comment: I agree with @rickhg12hs suspicion. But I'm also curious about this claim "_The data type doesn't seem to change even after I make updates to the document._". Can you elaborate on what specifically you are doing?

Comment: @user20042973 I was making update to the document using this method 

`model.findOne({_id: id}); 
model.status = parseInt(1); 
model.save();`. 

It finally worked when I used

 `model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {status: 1})`.

Thanks for the heads-up @rickhg12hs

Comment: It may just be a typo by putting code in comments (generally preferable to edit the question and add it there), but that code isn't right. You'd need to set a variable to the (`await`ed) _result_ of the `findOne()` and then modify and `.save()` it. As written you weren't modifying the document that the `findOne()` call returned as far as I can tell

Comment: There was no typo. I just didn't include that part. I used it just like you said and it didn't work. @user20042973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from using `findOne`

```
mySchema.statics.updateStatus = async function(id, status){
  try{
    const record = await this.findOne({_id: id});
    if(record){
      record.status = parseInt(status);
    }
    const updatedRecord = await record.save();
    return updatedRecord;
  }catch(err){
    return null;
  }
}
```

To using `fineOneAndUpdate`

```
mySchema.statics.updateStatus = async function(id, status){
  try{
    const record = await this.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:id }, {status}, {
      returnOriginal: false
    });
  
    return record;
  }catch(err){
    return null;
  }
}
```

And it updated the data type in the DB.